# Software Riddle

Tags: riddle

```
 This riddle is a computer program/language. Enjoy!
```

I used to love the Sun
Now I pray to my oracle
I'm said to virtualize all
I'm not picky, working anywhere...

I love my classes-all of them
I love my matter-known as objects
I love running parallel-too lazy to wait
Fans worldwide build and break with me!

My syntax-derived from a letter
many programmers found me familiar
I have nothing included-very greedy
And I must import all!

> I want every line torn apart, as this is an easy one :)

Comment: After the first line, I knew it already :P.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are

> Java

I used to love the Sun
Now I pray to my oracle

> Sun Microsystems used to be the standards keeper for the JRE and JDK; now Oracle Ltd. has inherited that role.

I'm said to virtualize all
I'm not picky, working anywhere...

> All methods in Java classes are what C++ calls `virtual` by default, referring to the fact that they are dynamically bound. Java code is deployable across numerous operating systems and platforms, in numerous "flavours" (standard, micro, and enterprise). A great deal of firmware also runs on Java.

I love my classes-all of them
I love my matter-known as objects

> Java OOP structure primitives are called `class`es, and all Java classes are a subclass of `Object`

I love running parallel-too lazy to wait
Fans worldwide build and break with me!

> Java 5 and later come with a significant concurrency (i.e. parallel execution) API. Java enjoys a broad adoption in numerous platforms worldwide.

My syntax-derived from a letter
many programmers found me familiar

> Java inherits much of its syntax from the programming language **C**.

I have nothing included-very greedy
And I must import all!

> By default, without imports, a Java file only has access to other classes in its package and classes in `java.lang.*`, which is an incredibly sparse collection of objects such as boxing primitives, `System` interface methods, and some common exceptions.

Comment: I was working on this when you got it

Comment: @michaelpri: I scooped you, did I? ;)

Comment: Gah, you were faster than me as well! +1

Comment: me too :p FGITW

Comment: Good job! You did it... Technically, the fans part referred to Minecraft... But good job!

Answer (score 0):

> Java

---

**Unspoilered explanations below:**

> I used to love the Sun
>   Now I pray to my oracle

It used to be owned by the company Sun, but Oracle has since bought Sun. ([Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)#History))

> I'm said to virtualize all

Everything is an object in this language.

> I'm not picky, working anywhere...

Its motto is "write once, run anywhere," and one of its design goals was to be cross-platform.

> I love my classes-all of them
>   I love my matter-known as objects

Again, this language is OOP and everything is an object.

> I love running parallel-too lazy to wait

Code can run in parallel with threads in this language.

> Fans worldwide build and break with me!

"Write once, run anywhere" - it can even run on fans / refrigerators / etc.; it's also used worldwide.

> My syntax-derived from a letter
>   many programmers found me familiar

This is a C-based language.

> I have nothing included-very greedy
>   And I must import all!

Technically, `<language name>.lang.*` is imported by default, but most other classes must be explicitly `import`ed.

Comment: Can I ask why you would answer a challenge question after closing a similar one?