# Software Riddle [Part 2!]

Tags: riddle

*The original by [quynguyen2013](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5368/quynguyen2013) can be found here; [Software Riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5823/software-riddle)*

> I compile quickly, yet I'm dynamic.
>   I was developed by a company you know well.
>   I'm open-sourced and a lot like a snake.
>   I also tend to be like a letter in the alphabet.

It's not too hard, but you have to explain every line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Go

---

**Nonspoilered explanations below:**

> I compile quickly, yet I'm dynamic.

This language was designed to compile very quickly. It's statically typed, but [there are ways to achieve dynamic typing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20518457/1223693).

> I was developed by a company you know well.

It was developed by Google.

> I'm open-sourced and a lot like a snake.

It is indeed open source, and it was influenced heavily by Python.

> I also tend to be like a letter in the alphabet.

Certain components of this language could be somewhat comparable to the C programming language (such as the `main` function).

Comment: the hypocrisy is strong in this one.

Comment: @Bozman - Indeed. It would be nice if this 'knob could decide whether he's anti-challenge or willing to participate in challenge questions.

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> C

because *I also tend to be like a letter in the alphabet* makes me think so.